# Highcharts Integration with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, highcharts

I'm trying to create a Highcharts' line chart on Codeigniter.
1. Here is my JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Category",
        "data": [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "May",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "WordPress",
        "data": [
            4,
            5,
            6,
            2,
            5,
            7,
            2,
            1,
            6,
            7,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Code Igniter",
        "data": [
            5,
            2,
            3,
            6,
            7,
            1,
            2,
            6,
            6,
            4,
            6,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Highcharts",
        "data": [
            7,
            8,
            9,
            6,
            7,
            10,
            9,
            7,
            6,
            9,
            8,
            4
        ]
    }
]
```

2. I'm getting the data from MySql, here is the controller: ("chart.php")

   ```
   class Chart extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct()
   {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('data');
   }

   public function index()
   {
   $this->load->view('chart');
   }

   public function data()
   {

   $data = $this->data->get_data();

   $category = array();
   $category['name'] = 'Category';

   $series1 = array();
   $series1['name'] = 'WordPress';

   $series2 = array();
   $series2['name'] = 'Code Igniter';

   $series3 = array();
   $series3['name'] = 'Highcharts';

   foreach ($data as $row)
   {
   $category['data'][] = $row->month;
   $series1['data'][] = $row->wordpress;
   $series2['data'][] = $row->codeigniter;
   $series3['data'][] = $row->highcharts;
   }

   $result = array();
   array_push($result,$category);
   array_push($result,$series1);
   array_push($result,$series2);
   array_push($result,$series3);

   print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
   }

   }
   ?>
   ```
3. Then Below is my View ("index.php"), when I try to load it, nothing happens (I got a blank screen)

   ```
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <title>Line Chart</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           var options = {
               chart: {
                   renderTo: 'container',
                   type: 'line',
                   marginRight: 130,
                   marginBottom: 25
               },
               title: {
                   text: 'Project Requests',
                   x: -20 //center
               },
               subtitle: {
                   text: '',
                   x: -20
               },
               xAxis: {
                   categories: []
               },
               yAxis: {
                   title: {
                       text: 'Requests'
                   },
                   plotLines: [{
                       value: 0,
                       width: 1,
                       color: '#808080'
                   }]
               },
               tooltip: {
                   formatter: function() {
                           return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                           this.x +': '+ this.y;
                   }
               },
               legend: {
                   layout: 'vertical',
                   align: 'right',
                   verticalAlign: 'top',
                   x: -10,
                   y: 100,
                   borderWidth: 0
               },

               series: []
           }


           $.getJSON('data.php', function(json) {
               options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
               options.series.push(json[1]);
               options.series.push(json[2]);
               options.series.push(json[3]);
               var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
           });
       });
       </script>
       <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
       <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="container" name="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   </body>
   ```

   4. And used the model ("data.php") as follows:
      `class Data extends CI_Model {
            function __construct(){ 
               parent::__construct();
          }
           function get_data(){
              $this->db->select('month, wordpress, codeigniter, highcharts');
              $this->db->from('project_requests');
              $query = $this->db->get();
             return $query->result();
          }
      }`

I did not point the issue what may be wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: you forgot to mention the issue ? what is the issue

Comment: @chhameed. Pls. see under topic no. 3 as -> "when I try to load it, nothing happens (I got a blank screen) - Means did not created the Line Chart"

Comment: @MCITTrends check any console errors and also check that you are getting data in function ` $.getJSON('data.php', function(json) {})`

Comment: @Deep 3015. Checked that. But still with the issue

Comment: Maybe the source of problem is that you import Highcharts **after** you execute your JS code. Move lines responsible for importing Highcharts so that they're right after the script that imports jQuery.